# " Item can't be played " whenever I tap on a song

Tags: iphone, ios, music, error

I'm currently using iPhone 6 with iOS9.3.1. Whenever I try to play music I get an error. After I tap on a song I get the error `item can't be played`.  Also, I have tried restarting my iPhone multiple times but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: We probably need more info before anyone can even guess. Do you use iTunes Match or Apple Music, or are these files just synced from iTunes directly?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too (itunes 12.4.1.6-ipad 2). If you're trying to sync over wi-fi, try plugging in directly with the cable... worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Reset your Phone and will work fine, this is the official solutions if is happen to not work your phone. when will make factory reset your device work normally.

Comment: I would down-vote this answer, if I could.